# SSMS Rank() function. How can partition by a range of values rather than an exact value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm using a rank() and a row_number() function in some sql code.  Everything is working fine except for parts where I have records that have [np_Exposure_Total] values as 20134446 vs. 20134447.  I want these to essentially be treated as if they were the same number.  I'm thinking ideally I would like to do it by something like either if the value is within plus or minus 3, or within multiplying or dividing by 1.05 for example.

In my code below if this is the case the row_number function will start over at 1 and not continue counting the next one as 3 and in the rank function it won't rank them as if they are part of the same grouping.

```
SELECT [account_ID]
      ,[np_Country]
      ,[np_NAICS]
      ,[np_Exposure_Total]
      ,[lookup]
      ,[NAICS]
      ,[NAICS Description]
      ,[Indigenous Prods]
      ,rank() over (Partition by [account_ID], [np_Country], [np_Exposure_Total] ORDER BY [Indigenous Prods] asc) as Ind_Rank
      ,Row_Number() over (Partition by [account_ID], [np_Country], [np_Exposure_Total] ORDER BY [Indigenous Prods] asc) as Ind_Row
  FROM [Null_Limits].[dbo].[Variable to Risk Code Link]
  ORDER BY [account_ID] asc
```

My output is 
[image: Sample Output]

Answer (score 2):

Use `case`:

```
  rank() over (Partition by [account_ID], [np_Country],
                            (case when [np_Exposure_Total] in (20134446, 20134447) then 20134446
                                  else np_Exposure_Total
                             end)
               ORDER BY [Indigenous Prods] asc
               ) as Ind_Rank
```

Don't start fiddling with the values (by doing something like `floor(np_Exposure_Total*1.0001)`), because this could have unintended side effects for other values.  Only put in such an expression if you want the logic for *all* values that are close to each other.